# Output deprecation error

Tags: craft3

Good Evening,

Please bear with me I'm very new to Craft 3. I'm getting deprecation errors when outputting information.

I'm trying to output a single entry from a section using the following:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('homepage') %}{{ entry.richText }}{% endfor %}
```

It is giving me the following error:

> Looping through element queries directly has been deprecated. Use the all() function to fetch the query results before looping over them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `for entry in craft.entries.section('homepage')` is attempting to loop through `homepage` entries as though they're an array. In Craft CMS 3, this is now deprecated just like the error message is telling you.

That means you need to use `.all()` when querying entries, meaning...

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('homepage') %}
```

...becomes...

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('homepage').all() %}
```

Ryan Irelan produced [a nice video about this](https://mijingo.com/lessons/using-dot-all-in-craft-3-element-queries/) and it's also [covered explicitly in the Craft 3 docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#element-queries). If you've worked with Craft 2 and you're just getting started with Craft 3, that [*Changes in Craft 3*](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html) guide is an excellent place to start.

Comment: Perfect thank you Matt,  im returning to craft after quite some time, so appreciate the heads up.  Is there a quick guide for outputing images from an entry?

Comment: It depends on how you've configured your Entries, and _how_ you want to output that image. You'll probably want to take a look at the [templating section of the Assets Fields docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/assets-fields.html#templating), and if you're getting used to Craft again it might help more broadly to take a look at the [Happy Lager demo site](https://github.com/craftcms/demo) to see some common patterns in the context of a small site.

Comment: Im using an Asset field called 'banner', within a section called 'homepage',  I assumed id be able to call the url from it easily. i must be missing something

Comment: That doesn't seem relevant to the question or answer here. If you're looking for examples, I still strongly recommend looking through the Happy Lager demo site I linked to. If you'd like to chat with someone this isn't the right place for that, but the Craft CMS Slack group is perfect: https://craftcms.com/community.

Please consider asking clear questions here and staying on topic, and accepting answers (on _any_ Stack Exchange site) that you find to be most helpful.