# .all() — Looping through element queries directly has been deprecated

Tags: craft3, templating, php

This is very nearly a duplicate question but I can't figure out where to insert [`.all()`](https://mijingo.com/lessons/using-dot-all-in-craft-3-element-queries/) to execute my [element query](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/element-queries.html#executing-element-queries). I'm still asking because I may be messing up php, function or filter syntax somewhere. I've looked through other related answers ([1](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/29366/output-deprecation-error), [2](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/35244/looping-through-element-queries-directly-has-been-deprecated)).

I traced the error to the template(s) below. The first `_entry.twig` chooses a layout based on url parameters and Admin CP settings:

```
{% block content %}
  {% if craft.app.request.segments|length == 3 %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries().slug(slug|literal).one() %}
    {% include "shared/_grid-item" with {
      entry: entry,
      index: number,
    } only %}

  {% elseif entry.galleryShowThumbnailPage|length %}
    {% include "shared/_grid" with { entry: entry } %}

  {% else %}
    {% include "shared/_gallery" with { entry: entry } %}
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I'm fairly sure the error is **not** coming from `_entry.twig` but may be caused by the variable `entry` in the `shared/_grid-item.twig` partial it gets passed to:

```
{% set images = entry.galleryImages.withTransforms(['sideScrollImage', 'tinyThumb']).all() %}
{% set itemImage = images[index - 1] %}
{% set itemImages = []|merge([itemImage]) %}
{% if itemImage.relatedImages.exists() %}
  {% set itemImages = itemImages|merge(itemImage.relatedImages) %}
{% endif %}

{% set next = entry.url ~ '/' ~ (index + 1) %}
{% set prev = entry.url ~ '/' ~ (index - 1) %}
{% if index == 1 %}{% set prev = false %}{% endif %}
{% if index == (images|length) %}{% set next = false %}{% endif %}

{% extends "_layouts/_default.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    <main role="main" class="content">
      <h1 class="content__title content__title--hidden">
        {{ entry.title }}
      </h1>

      {% include "_partials/_sideScroll" with {
        back: entry.title,
        images: itemImages,
        next: next,
        prev: prev,
      } only %}
    </main>
  {% cache %}
  {% endcache %}
{% endblock %}
```

My understanding of the element query is that I call a for loop but then execute it by calling `.all()`. I'm not sure if any of the code in `_grid-item.twig` would call a for loop I'm unaware of – maybe in
`{% set itemImages = []|merge([itemImage]) %}`
or
`{% set itemImages = itemImages|merge(itemImage.relatedImages) %}`?
Does some of the php syntax need to change to allow adding `.all()`?

I've tried adding `.all()` various places like `{% set itemImage = images.all()[index - 1] %}` but everything throws a twig runtime error.

Comment: What kind of field is “entry.galleryShowThumbnailPage”?

Comment: `entry.galleryShowThumbnailPage` is a checkbox field type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is likely this line:

```
{% set itemImages = itemImages|merge(itemImage.relatedImages) %}
```

The `|merge` filter treats the `relatedImages` field as an array, which is why you get that deprecation error.

So to fix it, add the `.all()` call to execute the query (which will return an array), before merging:

```
{% set itemImages = itemImages|merge(itemImage.relatedImages.all()) %}
```

A tip that could make it easier to track down issues like these in the future, is to enable [`devMode`](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/what-dev-mode-does), and add this to your `config/app.php` config file:

```php
return [
    'components' => [
        'deprecator' => [
            'throwExceptions' => YII_DEBUG,
        ],
    ],
];
```

That will make Craft throw an actual PHP exception for deprecated code, with a full stack trace (instead of just logging the deprecation), which can make it easier to debug this stuff.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Works like a charm. I've enabled the deprecator in my config. It was really tough to find which templates were causing the issue in the stack trace before.